# Why do I get the frames in my .smd model importer gets messed up?

Tags: java, opengl

Have i missed something or is there anything wrong with my code?

The following links might be helpful:

- [SMD File Structure](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Studiomdl_Data)
- [The Source Code](https://bitbucket.org/vkuchalskis/for-gajet/src/a7371332834e/SDMimport)

I wrote a .smd model importer, and for some reason all frames except the at-rest frame are messed up.

First I load all information from the files and store it into arraylists. Then I call this method and calculate everything for rendering:

```
private void CalculateMatrices(Model model) {
    for(Bone bone : model.bones){
        if(bone.boneParentsID >= 0) {
            bone.parent = model.bones.get(bone.boneParentsID);
        }
        Matrix4f defaultBoneTransform = new Matrix4f();
        defaultBoneTransform.rotate(bone.defaultRotation.x, new Vector3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)); 
        defaultBoneTransform.rotate(bone.defaultRotation.y, new Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)); 
        defaultBoneTransform.rotate(bone.defaultRotation.z, new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)); 
        defaultBoneTransform.translate(bone.defaultPosition);
        bone.defaultBoneTransform = defaultBoneTransform;

        for(Frame frame : bone.frames){
            Matrix4f boneTransform = new Matrix4f();
            boneTransform.rotate(frame.rotation.x, new Vector3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)); 
            boneTransform.rotate(frame.rotation.y, new Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)); 
            boneTransform.rotate(frame.rotation.z, new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)); 
            boneTransform.translate(frame.position);
            bone.boneTransforms.add(boneTransform);
        }
    }
    for(Bone bone : model.bones){
        Matrix4f atRestTransform = new Matrix4f();
        if(bone.boneParentsID == -1) {
            atRestTransform = new Matrix4f(bone.defaultBoneTransform);
        } else {
            for (Bone current = bone; current != null; current = current.parent) {
                Matrix4f.mul(current.defaultBoneTransform, atRestTransform, atRestTransform);
            }
        }
        bone.boneToWorldDefault = new Matrix4f(atRestTransform);
        atRestTransform.invert();
        bone.atRestTransform = new Matrix4f(atRestTransform);

        for(Frame frame : bone.frames){
            Matrix4f boneToWorldTransform = new Matrix4f();
                if(bone.boneParentsID == -1) {
                    boneToWorldTransform = new Matrix4f(bone.boneTransforms.get(frame.time));
                } else {
                    for (Bone current = bone; current != null; current = current.parent) {
                        Matrix4f.mul(current.boneTransforms.get(frame.time), boneToWorldTransform, boneToWorldTransform);
                        }
            }
        bone.boneToWorldTransforms.add(new Matrix4f(boneToWorldTransform));
        }
    }
    for (Vertex vertex : model.vertices) {
        for (Frame frame : model.bones.get(0).frames) { 
        List<Vector4f> vertexPosAnimatedList = new ArrayList<Vector4f>();
        for (float boneID : vertex.boneIDs) {
        Vector4f vertexPosAnimated = new Vector4f();
        Bone bone = model.bones.get((int) boneID);
        Matrix4f mul = new Matrix4f();
        Matrix4f.mul(bone.boneToWorldTransforms.get(frame.time), bone.atRestTransform, mul);

        Vector4f vecPosMod = new Vector4f(vertex.position.x, vertex.position.y, vertex.position.z, 1f);
        Matrix4f.transform(mul, vecPosMod, vertexPosAnimated);
        vertexPosAnimated.scale(vertex.boneW.get(vertex.boneIDs.indexOf(boneID)));
        vertexPosAnimatedList.add(vertexPosAnimated);
        }
        Vector4f vertexPosAnimated1 = new Vector4f();
        for(int i = 0; i < vertexPosAnimatedList.size(); i++) {
            if(i == 0) {
                vertexPosAnimated1 = vertexPosAnimatedList.get(0);
            } else {
                Vector4f.add(vertexPosAnimated1, vertexPosAnimatedList.get(i), vertexPosAnimated1);
            }
        }
        Vector3f animatedPos = new Vector3f(vertexPosAnimated1.x, vertexPosAnimated1.y, vertexPosAnimated1.z);
        vertex.positionOnFrames.add(animatedPos);
        }
    }
}
```

And the rendering:

```
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (Vertex vertex : model.vertices) {
        Vector3f pos = vertex.positionOnFrames.get(curFrame);
        GL11.glNormal3f(model.normals.get(model.vertices.indexOf(vertex)).x, model.normals.get(model.vertices.indexOf(vertex)).y, model.normals.get(model.vertices.indexOf(vertex)).z);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(model.textures.get(model.vertices.indexOf(vertex)).x, model.textures.get(model.vertices.indexOf(vertex)).y);
        GL11.glVertex3f(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
    }
    GL11.glEnd();
```

I guess the problem is somewhere in the `CalculateMatrices` method.

In that method:

1. Create a transformation matrix for every bone and every frame, which
   includes bones rotation and translation.
2. Calculate bones atrestposition, and it's world position on every
   frame.
3. Do more calculations like setting multiple bones for a vertex.
4. Store each vertex with its animated position into array list.